# I am not able to call recyclerview adapter's functions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, custom-adapter, realm-mobile-platform

I have a recyclerView adapter named as CustomAdapter in the MainActivity, I am getting the data by parsing the JSON and this data is used to set the textview inCustomAdapter class.

When I start my application,I am not showing the recyclerView list and the adapter is not being called. So my problem is I am not able to call the customAdapter's functions like onBindViewHolder,onCreateViewHolder.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        Context context;
        RealmResults<Film> realmResults;
        View.OnTouchListener listener;
        Realm realm;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, View.OnTouchListener listener) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View root = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_liste, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(root);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            Realm.init(context);
            RealmResults<Film> films = realm.where(Film.class).findAll();
            Film f = films.get(position);

            for(film film:filmler) {
                try {
                    holder.title.setText(film.getTitle());
                    holder.year.setText(film.getYear());
                    holder.poster.setImageURI(film.getPoster());

                    if (film.getPoster().toString().equals("N/A") == true) {
                        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.noImage).fit().into(holder.image);
                    } else {
                        Picasso.get().load(film.getPoster()).into(holder.image);
                    }

                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            if(realmResults==null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return realmResults.size();
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnTouchListener {

            public TextView title, year;
            public ImageView image;
            public LinearLayout linearLayout;

            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_id);
                year = itemView.findViewById(R.id.year_id);
                image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
                linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_id);
                linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(listener);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

My MainActivity Class:

```
final StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response) {
          progressDialog.dismiss();
          JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(response);
          String response = jsonObject1.getString("Response");

          if (response.equals("True") && jsonObject1.has("Search")==true) {

          JSONArray array1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Search");
          for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {

          final JSONObject films = array1.getJSONObject(i);

           realm1.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
              @Override
              public void execute(Realm realm1) {
                Film film = realm1.createObject(Film.class);
                  try {        
                       film.setTitle(filmler.getString("Title"));                                     
                       film.setYear(filmler.getString("Year"));                                 
                       film.setPoster(filmler.getString("Poster"));
                       realm1.copyToRealm(film);
                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       }
                });

            }

             for (int j = 0; j < array1.length(); j++) {
                array1.remove(j);
             }
             adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, this);
             recycle1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: set recycler view visibility as gone..

Comment: complete code with screen where you had added adapter in recyclerView

Comment: I added MainActivity code. Recycler view visibility is visible

Comment: It looks like you are not updating realmResults from Activity after getting response from server.

Comment: @Dhaval How can i update realmResults ? I used to "realm1.copyToRealm(film_ozellik);"

Comment: Not sure about your getItemCount(). It seems to be always 0. Also onBindViewHolder is wrong. You are not getting the value from the position value.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Yes it comes 0. How can i Assign realmResult in main activity

Comment: @propoLis if it is 0, the recyclerView is empty. Pass it in the adapter constructor

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Should I assign realmResult in Main Activity class? I create a constructor for realmResult but getItemCount() comes 0 again.

Comment: In any case you have to update the realmResult inside the adapter

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti How can i set realmResult with realm object ? My realm object is full but realmResult is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are going wrong in onBindViewHolder. 
Try to pass list in constructor

```
   public CustomAdapter(Context context, View.OnTouchListener 
                                 listener,RealmResults<film> realmResults) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.realmResults = realmResults;
    }
```

and Remove this code from bindViewHolder

```
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder : called.");
        Realm.init(context);
        //film filmler = filmList.get(position);
        //realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<film> filmler = 
        realm.where(film.class).findAll();
        film f = filmler.get(position);
```

don't call for loop there in onBindViewHolder for set data just do following

```
        @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int 
        position) {
                 film item = realmResults.get(position);
                 if(item!=null && item.isValid()){
                       holder.baslik.setText(item.getTitle());
                holder.yil.setText(item.getYear());
                holder.resim.setImageURI(item.getPoster());

                if (item.getPoster().toString().equals("N/A")) {
                    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.resimyok).fit().into(holder.resim);
                } else {

              Picasso.get().load(film.getPoster()).into(holder.resim);
                }
                 }
            }
```

Fix this below for getting response and save it to realm

```
          JSONArray array1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Search");
                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(filn.class, array1);
                    realm.commitTransaction();

                    //get all saved data from realm
                    RealmResults<T> results = 
                      realm.where(film.class).query.findAll();
                    adapter = new 
             CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.this,results);
                    recycle1.setAdapter(adapter);
                    arama.getText().clear();
```

Comment: I added this in onCreate Method, MainActivity class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I set realmResult in MainActivity ? I only assign realm object @govind-prajapati

Comment: yes you can get realm list in MainActivity where you set the adapter, then pass into CustomAdapter as I show in answer.

Comment: How can I set realmResult with realm object? My realm object is full but realmResult is null

Comment: I am again updating code for get response and set it into adapter

Comment: Thank you. It is ok but again realmResult is null :( . In Main activity class, Should I update realmResult ? if yes, how?

Comment: Oh I found, I added this code in main activity and comes full item. Thank you so much :)